# Temporary visa changes to spouse visa in Japan

Tags: visa, marriage, japan

I’m currently studying Japanese in Japan. My current visa is going to expire on 31st March. I will change my visa status from a student visa to a temporary visit visa, and I will get married with my Japanese girlfriend. I want to know if it's possible to change a temporary visit visa to a spouse visa, and if so, how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to switch from tourist visa to other status while in Japan?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4372/is-it-possible-to-switch-from-tourist-visa-to-other-status-while-in-japan)

Comment: However, this question is about how to switch specifically _to_ a spouse visa, and the other question is how to switch _from_ a tourist visa to anything else. Not exactly the same

Comment: I don't know, but for the benefit of anyone else reading this, it's probably a lot easier to go directly from the student to spouse status and avoid the grey area of temporary visitor. It's been a few months anyway, how did it work out?

Comment: Also wondering how this worked out