# Change of status in visa Japan

Tags: visa, working-visas, dependent-visa, japan, visa-change

I have work visa of Japan. I am going to marry in the month of April. It takes some time to get the marriage certificate, so my wife will come with me on tourist visa. Can we convert to dependent visa later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited)

I assume that you are asking if your wife could change her *Status of Residence* from "Temporary Visitor" (which includes Tourists) to one that of a "Dependent".

The answer for that is "Yes, you can." However, since it takes about 1-3 months to process her application, she may want to apply *also* for a **Certificate of Eligibility** (CoE) when she makes the application for the change. This is because her "Temporary Visitor" *Status of Residence* may expire while waiting for the change to be approved.

See [related post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4372/is-it-possible-to-switch-from-tourist-visa-to-other-status-while-in-japan) and links below.

[Application for Certificate of Eligibility](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/tetuduki/kanri/shyorui/01.html)

[Application for Change of Status of Residence](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/tetuduki/kanri/shyorui/02.html)